# Facebook Graph API does not return shares but comment count and like count are ok

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get shares, comments and likes count from Facebook graph API. Everything works great except the shares did not return in the response payload.

Here is the params I sent:

```
mypost_id?fields=message,shares,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)
```

Here is the response

```json
{
  "message": "HUAWEI WiFi Router AX3",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 2,
      "can_like": true,
      "has_liked": true
    }
  },
  "comments": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "order": "ranked",
      "total_count": 2,
      "can_comment": true
    }
  },
  "id": "103851678893717_115163661095852"
}
```

Here is the graph API screenshot

[image]

I've noticed that the **shares** parameter was marked as grey ( see in the figure above ), there might be something wrong with it.

I am using Facebook graph v13.0.

Is there anyone experiencing this issue before?

Comment: Looks like the API only returns `shares`, if there are any actual shares. For posts with no shares, this is simply completely omitted from the result. For posts that do have shares, you should get `"shares": { "count": xy }` in the resulting structure.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to share with my account. It did share to my personal profile however the shares count did not increase on the page. After asking a friend to do it instead, it works just like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the API only returns `shares`, if there are any actual shares.

For posts with no shares, this is simply completely omitted from the result.

For posts that do have shares, you should get `"shares": { "count": xy }` in the resulting structure.